# Transfer Excel data to another Excel file - Power automate

Tags: excel, sharepoint, power-automate

I'd like to get some advice from this community on the best way update an excel file with new information. I'll first give some background on this project. Each year, we collect underwriting survey information from members of our program. This data includes population, worker hours, etc. The survey is sent out in excel format and is quite extensive. Each tab of the excel file has multiple sheets with several questions in each sheet.

We then have to manually enter this information into a master excel file where we have each member where we have multiple sheets and each member represented as a column header and the questions in the row headers.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to gather this information so that the master can be manually updated with the responses from members. I've thought about a MS Form and having members complete the form instead of the excel file and then using the Form as the trigger, but this will not work because of how extensive the questions are and each member needs to consult with various departments to get the answers. MS Form does not have a save and continue feature.

Looking for recommendations from you experts out there.

Comment: Use Office Scripts. You just gotta get each completed workbook to OneDrive/SharePoint so you can trigger the script. You can do that in a fairly controlled manner by using a form. There are a few ways to skin this cat.

Comment: I haven't used office scripts before but it seems this might be the best way to do what I'm looking to accomplish. Thanks for the advice on this.